# Ordering Permutation in Rcpp i.e. base::order()

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a ton of code using the *base::order()* command and I am really too lazy to code around that in rcpp. Since Rcpp only supports sort, but not order, I spent 2 minutes creating this function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector order_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector invec){
  int leng = invec.size();
  NumericVector y = clone(invec);
  for(int i=0; i<leng; ++i){
    y[sum(invec<invec[i])] = i+1;
  }
  return(y);
}
```

It somehow works. If the vectors are containing unique numbers, I get the same result as order(). If they are not unique, results are different, but not wrong (no unique solution really).

Using it:

```
c=sample(1:1000,500)
all.equal(order(c),order_cpp(c))
microbenchmark(order(c),order_cpp(c))

Unit: microseconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
     order(c)   33.507   36.223   38.035   41.356   78.785   100
 order_cpp(c) 2372.889 2427.071 2466.312 2501.932 2746.586   100
```

Ouch!
I need an efficient algorithm. 
Ok, so I [dug up](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2013/05/14/much-more-efficient-bubble-sort-in-r-using-the-rcpp-and-inline-packages/) a bubblesort implementation and adapted it:

```
 // [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector bubble_order_cpp2(Rcpp::NumericVector vec){                                  
       double tmp = 0;
       int n = vec.size();
              Rcpp::NumericVector outvec = clone(vec);
       for (int i = 0; i <n; ++i){
         outvec[i]=static_cast<double>(i)+1.0;
       }

       int no_swaps;
       int passes;
       passes = 0;
       while(true) {
           no_swaps = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < n - 1 - passes; ++i) {
               if(vec[i] > vec[i+1]) {
                   no_swaps++;
                   tmp = vec[i];
                   vec[i] = vec[i+1];
                   vec[i+1] = tmp;
                   tmp = outvec[i]; 
                   outvec[i] = outvec[i+1];  
                   outvec[i+1] = tmp; 
               };
           };
           if(no_swaps == 0) break;
           passes++;
       };       
       return(outvec);
}
```

Well, it's better - but not great:

```
microbenchmark(order(c),order_cpp(c),bubble_order_cpp2(c),sort(c),c[order(c)])
Unit: microseconds
                 expr      min       lq    median        uq      max neval
             order(c)   33.809   38.034   40.1475   43.3170   72.144   100
         order_cpp(c) 2339.080 2435.675 2478.5385 2526.8350 3535.637   100
 bubble_order_cpp2(c)  219.752  231.977  234.5430  241.1840  322.383   100
              sort(c)   59.467   64.749   68.2205   75.4645  148.815   100
          c[order(c)]   38.336   41.204   44.3735   48.1460   93.878   100
```

Another finding: It's faster to order than to sort.

Well, then for shorter vectors:

```
c=sample(1:100)
 microbenchmark(order(c),order_cpp(c),bubble_order_cpp2(c),sort(c),c[order(c)])
Unit: microseconds
                 expr    min       lq   median       uq     max neval
             order(c) 10.566  11.4710  12.8300  14.1880  63.089   100
         order_cpp(c) 95.689 100.8200 102.7825 107.3105 198.018   100
 bubble_order_cpp2(c)  9.962  11.1700  12.0750  13.2830  64.598   100
              sort(c) 39.242  41.5065  42.5620  46.3355 155.758   100
          c[order(c)] 11.773  12.6790  13.5840  15.9990  82.710   100
```

Oh well, I have overlooked an RcppArmadillo function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector ordera(arma::vec x) {
  return(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(Rcpp::wrap(arma::sort_index( x )+1)) );
}

microbenchmark(order(c),order_(c),ordera(c))
Unit: microseconds
      expr   min     lq median     uq    max neval
  order(c) 9.660 11.169 11.773 12.377 46.185   100
 order_(c) 4.529  5.133  5.736  6.038 34.413   100
 ordera(c) 4.227  4.830  5.434  6.038 60.976   100
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple version leveraging Rcpp sugar to implement an `order` function. We put in a check for duplicates so that we guarantee that things work 'as expected'. (There is also a bug with Rcpp's `sort` method when there are `NA`s, so that may want to be checked as well -- this will be fixed by the next release).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector order_(NumericVector x) {
  if (is_true(any(duplicated(x)))) {
    Rf_warning("There are duplicates in 'x'; order not guaranteed to match that of R's base::order");
  }
  NumericVector sorted = clone(x).sort();
  return match(sorted, x);
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- runif(1E5)
identical( order(x), order_(x) )
microbenchmark(
  order(x),
  order_(x)
)
*/
```

gives me

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/test-order.cpp')

> set.seed(456)

> library(microbenchmark)

> x <- runif(1E5)

> identical( order(x), order_(x) )
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark(
+   order(x),
+   order_(x)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
  order(x) 15.48007 15.69709 15.86823 16.21142 17.22293   100
 order_(x) 10.81169 11.07167 11.40678 11.87135 48.66372   100
>
```

Of course, if you're comfortable with the output not matching R, you can remove the duplicated check -- `x[order_(x)]` will still be properly sorted; more specifically, `all(x[order(x)] == x[order_(x)])` should return `TRUE`.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty good and pretty fast. I thought about match too, but I don't like the behavior with duplicates. I would like to return some permutation with unique indicators, even if it is not a unique solution.

Comment: Maybe I could parse the vector and add +1 from duplicate to end of vector.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution based on the C++11:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
IntegerVector order_impl(const Vector<RTYPE>& x, bool desc) {
    auto n = x.size();
    IntegerVector idx = no_init(n);
    std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), static_cast<size_t>(1));
    if (desc) {
        auto comparator = [&x](size_t a, size_t b){ return x[a - 1] > x[b - 1]; };
        std::stable_sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), comparator);
    } else {
        auto comparator = [&x](size_t a, size_t b){ return x[a - 1] < x[b - 1]; };
        std::stable_sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), comparator);
        // simulate na.last
        size_t nas = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++nas)
            if (!Vector<RTYPE>::is_na(x[idx[i] - 1])) break;
        std::rotate(idx.begin(), idx.begin() + nas, idx.end());
    }
    return idx;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector order2(SEXP x, bool desc = false) {
    switch(TYPEOF(x)) {
    case INTSXP: return order_impl<INTSXP>(x, desc);
    case REALSXP: return order_impl<REALSXP>(x, desc);
    case STRSXP: return order_impl<STRSXP>(x, desc);
    default: stop("Unsupported type.");
    }
}

/***R
int <- sample.int(1000, 1E5, replace = TRUE)
dbl <- runif(1E5)
chr <- sample(letters, 1E5, replace = TRUE)
library(benchr)
benchmark(order(int), order2(int))
benchmark(order(dbl), order2(dbl))
benchmark(order(chr), order2(chr))
*/
```

Compare performance:

```r
R> int <- sample.int(1000, 1E5, replace = TRUE)

R> dbl <- runif(1E5)

R> chr <- sample(letters, 1E5, replace = TRUE)

R> library(benchr)

R> benchmark(order(int), order2(int))
Benchmark summary:
Time units : microseconds 
        expr n.eval  min lw.qu median mean up.qu  max  total relative
 order(int)    100  442   452    464  482   486 1530  48200      1.0
order2(int)    100 5150  5170   5220 5260  5270 6490 526000     11.2

R> benchmark(order(dbl), order2(dbl))
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
        expr n.eval   min lw.qu median  mean up.qu  max total relative
 order(dbl)    100 13.90 14.00  14.20 14.80  15.8 17.4  1480     1.98
order2(dbl)    100  7.11  7.13   7.15  7.26   7.3  8.8   726     1.00

R> benchmark(order(chr), order2(chr))
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
        expr n.eval   min lw.qu median  mean up.qu   max total relative
 order(chr)    100 128.0 131.0  133.0 133.0 134.0 148.0 13300     7.34
order2(chr)    100  17.7  17.9   18.1  18.2  18.3  22.2  1820     1.00
```

Note that `radix` method from the base `order` much faster.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach using `std::sort`.

```
typedef std::pair<int, double> paired;

bool cmp_second(const paired & left, const paired & right) {
    return left.second < right.second;
}

Rcpp::IntegerVector order(const Rcpp::NumericVector & x) {
    const size_t n = x.size();
    std::vector<paired> pairs;
    pairs.reserve(n);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pairs.push_back(std::make_pair(i, x(i)));

    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), cmp_second<paired>);

    Rcpp::IntegerVector result = Rcpp::no_init(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result(i) = pairs[i].first;
    return result;
}
```