# Rcpp sugar for rank function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

I have been trying to get the rank of a vector in c++ using Rcpp. I have used other sugar functions like

```
is_na();
```

Is there a similar sugar function for rank R function in c++. Also is there any list of available R sugar functions in Rcpp/

Comment: Hadley has list of sugar functions: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-sugar But I don't know how exhaustive it is. It shouldn't be too difficult to write your own rank function.

Comment: Thank you for the list and Ya its easy to implement my own rank().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1)** There is an `order` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609934/ordering-permutation-in-rcpp-i-e-baseorder) and `order(order(x))` is `rank(x, ties = "first")`.

**2)** A second way would be: `match(x, sort(x))`

**ADDED** Second approach.

Comment: Thank you second one is an elegant solution.