# Rcpp or Rcpp Armadillo Function/Code for R's Rank Function

Tags: r, rcpp, rank, rcpparmadillo

In short: Is there an rcpp or rcpparmadillo function that calculates rank with ties = "random"?

Long Summary:
I am trying to convert a program written in R to a combination of C++, Rcpp and Rcpp Armadillo. The R program makes use of the R function Rank on a numeric vector called "fitness.old". Some example calls are the following:

```
sort(pop[rank(fitness.old,ties.method="random")==1,])

sample(v,1,prob=rank(-fitness.old[v])
```

I have spent lots of time trying to find equivalent functions or code for Rank in Rcpp Armadillo or Rcpp but have had no luck. This post

[Rcpp sugar for rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606266/rcpp-sugar-for-rank-function)

was the closest I could find to a possible solution. However, I want rank(x, ties = "random") NOT rank(x, ties = "first"). Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Rcpp Armadillo solution:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
umat arma_rank(vec x) {
  umat d(x.n_rows,x.n_rows,fill::eye);
  umat res=index_max(d.rows(sort_index(x)))+1;
  return(res);
}

/*** R
x<-rnorm(100)
all(drop(arma_rank(x))==rank(x))
*/
```

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("arma_rank.cpp")

> x<-rnorm(100)

> all(drop(arma_rank(x))==rank(x))
[1] TRUE
>
```

much slower than `rank`:

```
> microbenchmark(arma_rank(x))
Unit: microseconds
         expr    min      lq     mean median     uq     max neval
 arma_rank(x) 78.761 79.3555 88.44151 81.795 84.788 708.275   100
> microbenchmark(rank(x))
Unit: microseconds
    expr   min    lq     mean median    uq     max neval
 rank(x) 7.339 7.544 12.63538 7.7285 8.446 428.081   100
>
```